# Make NSOutlineView work as Source List programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, rubymotion

Could you provide an example of how to create a Finder-like sidebar in RubyMotion? Here's a minimal example of where I am right now, but it is nothing like it.

So many apps have this kind of sidebar, including Mail, Contacts, Reminders and Notes. There should be a way of producing this interface without just mimicking it? Xcode seems to allow you to use NSOutlineView as "Source List", but is it possible to do so programmatically?

```
class AppDelegate
  def applicationDidFinishLaunching notification
    @window = NSWindow.alloc.initWithContentRect [[240, 180], [480, 360]],
      styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask,
      backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered, defer: false
    @window.orderFrontRegardless

    @outline_view = NSOutlineView.new
    @window.contentView.addSubview @outline_view
    @outline_view
      .setSelectionHighlightStyle NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList

    column = NSTableColumn.alloc.initWithIdentifier 'Column'
    column.editable = false
    column.minWidth = 150
    @outline_view.addTableColumn column
    @outline_view.outlineTableColumn = column
    @outline_view.delegate = self
    @outline_view.dataSource = self
    @outline_view.reloadData
  end

  def outlineView _, numberOfChildrenOfItem: item
    item == nil ? 5 : 0
  end

  def outlineView _, isItemExpandable: item
    false
  end

  def outlineView _, child: child, ofItem: item
    'test'
  end

  def outlineView _, objectValueForTableColumn: column, byItem: item
    item == nil ? 'root' : 'test'
  end
end
```

Comment: Using `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList` and not changing the background color should do the trick. It'll also enable the OS X 10.10 blurring/vibrancy effects on the outline view.
If you use a custom class for your cell -drawsBackground should return false.

Comment: @diederikh From code above you can see that I use `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList`, and do not change the background color. Also, I'm not using any custom classes—that's all the code. Also, I don't get vibrancy.